# FLutter error The plugin `flutter_bluetooth_basic` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: android, flutter

Hi I got an error " The plugin `flutter_bluetooth_basic` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it
since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
"
I already delete "flutter_bluetooth_basic" in pubspec.yaml and run flutter clean. I still got this error. Why is it?